# How can I split a dataframe and run custom fuctions on it parallely?

Tags: r, revolution-r, parallel-foreach

I have a large dataset with around 25L rows, where this function "status"         is applied. Its a flagging procedure. Inside the fn, operations are vectorised and apply functions are used. c1-c4 are the columns in my data. Still it takes about 5-6 hrs to execute the fn.

```
status(mydata)
status <- function (x) {  

x<- subset(x, x$RECORD_TYPE != "INPUT")
x$c1<- as.character(x$c1)
x$c2 <- as.factor(x$c2)
x$c3 <- as.factor(x$c3)
return ( data.frame(cbind( 
         tapply(x$c2,  x$c4, 
           function (x) ifelse (!(any(x=="BAD")), "G", sum(x== "BAD"))) ,
         tapply(x$c2D,  x$c4, 
            function (x) sum (x== "NEG"))  ))) 
                 }
```

Is there any way to further speed up the fn. I work in a server which has 16 cores. So i believe it can be further sped up.

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example for others to test

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a `data.table` approach would be faster than trying to parallelize your code, but I would need a sample of your data to make sure this answer addresses your question:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(mydata)

mydata[ RECORD_TYPE != "INPUT", 
                   .(var1 = ifelse (!(any(c2=="BAD")), "G", sum(c2== "BAD")),
                     var2 = sum (c2D== "NEG")), by= c4]
```